# Any idea why this code isn't running in parallel

Tags: c, macos, bash, parallel-processing, openmp

Below is my current code which as the title says, I thought would be running in parallel. I am working in Mac OSX, and in terminal I am using bash. The code is written in C and I am trying to use openmp. It compiles and runs without any errors, but I do not believe it is running in parallel.

To explain the code for easier understanding. First block is just declarations of a bunch of variables. The next chunk is the for loop, which runs commands in terminal.

First command is to run an executable program with four parameters: a double, a fixed integer, a string, and another fixed integer. The double is dependent on which iteration of the for loop you are on.

Second, third, fourth and fifth command all deal with renaming and moving files which the executable program spits out. And this completes the for loop. My hopes were that this for loop would run in parallel, since each iteration takes about 30 seconds.

Once outside the four loop, a file which has been written to in each loop is then moved. I realize the ordering which the file is written to might be faulty, but that is only going to be a concern when it is actually running in parallel!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int spot;
    double th;
    char command[50];
    char path0[] = "/home/path0";
    char path1[] = "/home/path1";
    char path2[] = "/home/path2";
    char path3[] = "/home/path3";

    #pragma omp parallel for private(command,path)
    for (th=0.004, spot =0; th<1; th += 0.005, spot++) {
        sprintf(command, "./program %lf 19 %s 418", th, path0);
        system(command);

        sprintf(command, "mv fileA.ppm a.%04d.ppm", spot);
        system(command);

        sprintf(command, "mv a.%04d.ppm %s", spot, path1);
        system(command);

        sprintf(command, "mv fileB.ppm b.%04d.ppm", spot);
        system(command);

        sprintf(command, "mv b.%04d.ppm %s", spot, path2);
        system(command);


    }

    sprintf(command, "mv FNums.txt %s", path3);
    system(command);


     return(0);
}
```

Thanks for any insight and help you guys can offer.

Comment: Depending on the scheduling granularity and how the processes are scheduled it's completely possible that all the work required is being finished in under one system timeslice and therefore looks sequential. How are you checking for parallelism?

Comment: Under the activity monitor for macs it show the the main program as 1 thread and 0 CPU usage, and for the program it calls it shows 1 thread and 100% CPU usage. Maybe I don't understand how openmp works but I thought the main program would be using on multiple threads.

Comment: Also timing was a big part of why I thought it was failing, but that is probably a poor check. But it is apparent from the performance report that only one core is doing any work.

Comment: Have you ensured that you are providing the correct compiler switches to enable OpenMP?

Comment: @paddy most likely not, but I will look into that. Would you be able to elaborate on that?

edit: do you mean -fopenmp for gcc 4.2 onwards. Then no haha. I will try that.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're doing this with OpenMP and not with xargs or GNU parallel?

Comment: @thatotherguy, because I know next to nothing about anything. Thus I've never really heard or seen much of anything about those. I'm guessing the other two are far superior somehow?

Comment: @NoviceC I haven't used gcc for ages, but just look up the command-line switches for OpenMP, and it should be pretty obvious.  Regarding comments on other approaches, it's quite common to use `fork` when you want to run a bunch of system calls.  You can fork your process into as many copies as you desire, then leave them to process a subset of the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is basically shell script based already, consider using xargs:

First of all, make sure multiple instances of `./program` don't overwrite each other's fileA.ppm if you run it in parallel. I'll assume you'll start writing them out as fileA.ppm.0.004 in this example.

Then make a script you can invoke with the spot number:

```
#!/bin/sh
spot=$1
th=$(echo "$spot" | awk '{print 0.004 + 0.005*$1 }')
./program "$th" 19 /home/path0 418
mv "fileA.ppm.$th" "$(printf '/home/path1/a.%04d.ppm' "$spot")"
mv "fileB.ppm.$th" "$(printf '/home/path2/b.%04d.ppm' "$spot")"
```

`chmod a+x yourscript`, and you can now run and test each instance using `./yourscript 0`, `./yourscript 1`, etc.

When it works, run them 8 (or more) in parallel using:

```
printf "%s\n" {0..199} | xargs -P 8 -n 1 ./yourscript
```

Comment: I will have to look into this definitely, ironically the code was originally written to run with a shell script. I didn't know how to do stuff in parallel without openmp (which I really don't know either) so I tried making a .c file to replace the shell script. I'm off to dinner now so I can't implement this immediately, but thank you very and I will update you on any successes later.